# Open Design Positions At Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

My name's Pieter and I'm the technical recruiter here at Stack Overflow.  I'm excited to announce that we're adding two new design positions to our creative team. Before really ramping this search up, we want to give you excellent folks dibs, because we wuv you.  Take a look at the roles below and submit an application if you're interested in being part of our future growth:

[Marketing Production Designer](http://grnh.se/w4v0di)

[Senior Product Designer](http://grnh.se/0b4cwe)

We’re also putting this on careers, etc, but given that we know we have an insanely talented community here, it seemed crazy not to make sure we let you know we’re looking for folks just like you.

Comment: Thanks! Really awesome of you all to keep us in mind for stuff like this.

Comment: Oh, cool of you to think of us first, appreciated! :D